# Python Markdown2 fenced-code-blocks indentation issue

Tags: python, html, css, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

#### **Context**:

I am building a static site generator for markdown files with python.
I chose to use the [Markdown2](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2) lib to convert *.md files into html articles and that works pretty well. I used a markdown [test file](http://%20https://markdown-it.github.io/) including code blocks. As I want them to be highlighted, I installed [Pygments-css](https://github.com/richleland/pygments-css) and used the ["fenced-code-blocks"](https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2/wiki/fenced-code-blocks) Markdown2 extra.
I use [Yattag](https://www.yattag.org/) to wrap the markdown rendered content in an `<article>`.

Here is the code:

```py
    def render_md(self, md_file_content, extras):
        f = self.generate() # generates doctype, head etc

        # the following returns a string like "03 minute(s) read" depending on article words count
        estimated_time = self.get_reading_time(md_file_content)

        # markdown2 returns a string containing html
        article = markdown2.markdown(md_file_content, extras=extras)
        # the two following lines handle emoji
        article = emoticons_to_emoji(article)
        article = emoji.emojize(article, use_aliases=True, variant="emoji_type")

        doc, tag, text = Doc().tagtext()

        with tag('article'):
            with tag('span', klass='article__date'):
                text(time.strftime(f'%Y %b %d - %H:%M {estimated_time}'))
            # the following allows me to append a string containing html "as is", not altered by Yattag
            doc.asis(article)

        return self.close_html(f + indent(doc.getvalue())) # self.close_html adds some closing tags and js script tags
```

here are the extras from my config file:

```yaml
extras: # Documentation on https://github.com/trentm/python-markdown2/wiki/Extras
  - code-friendly
  - cuddled-lists
  - fenced-code-blocks
  - tables
  - footnotes
  - smarty-pants
  - numbering
  - tables
  - strike
  - spoiler
```

Here is the *.md file excerpt:

````
    JS

    ```js
    var foo = function (bar) {
      return bar++;
    };

    console.log(foo(5));
    ```
````

#### **The issue**:

I can't get it properly indented. I feel that I'm missing something, here's what I get as an output:

```html
  <div class="codehilite">
    <pre>      
      <span></span>
      <code>
        <span class="kd">var</span>
        <span class="nx">foo</span>
        <span class="o">=</span>
        <span class="kd">function</span>
        <span class="p">(</span>
        <span class="nx">bar</span>
        <span class="p">)</span>
        <span class="p">{</span>
        <span class="k">return</span>
        <span class="nx">bar</span>
        <span class="o">++</span>
        <span class="p">;</span>
        <span class="p">};</span>
        <span class="nx">console</span>
        <span class="p">.</span>
        <span class="nx">log</span>
        <span class="p">(</span>
        <span class="nx">foo</span>
        <span class="p">(</span>
        <span class="mf">5</span>
        <span class="p">));</span>
      </code>
    </pre>
  </div>
```

[image: wrong output]

If I remove the extra, the content isn't rendered as a code block but as a simple `<p>` tag.

[image: output without fenced-code-blocks]

I get the use of `<span>` for highlighting, but how does one get the result indented as in the following (capture from Pycharm) ? I really don't understand how it is supposed to output that result.

[image: pycharm capture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the indent() method is messing it up try removing that and it is working fine for me, you can try it!

Comment: Thanks that was it ! I replied to myself as I found out myself and I don't know how I missed your answer. Silly me, I assumed that indent() method was only for html readability purposes. Now I know !